# Please reopen “much of the same” vs “much the same”

Tags: support, closed-questions

I've since emended the question. https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185214/50720

@MattEllen: I had intended the topic sentence to be my question: 'What are the similarities and differences?' Sadly, I don't know if they're the same; that comment only furthers my confusion. Please advise of suggestions or concerns.

@KitFox: Sadly, I don't know 'why you think it was closed'. Please advise of suggestions or concerns.  I have since emended, by following your instructive comment below it:

"If you want this question reopened, you need to explain what is on the other side of those links, and why you think there is or isn't a difference, and what other sources (like a dictionary) you have consulted"

Comment: You should learn to use the markdown formatting properly so that we don't need to see the full URLs. Also, you should provide more examples for both.

Comment: This request for reopening exhibits the same issues that the closed question does. You have not explained why you think it was closed, what you did to improve the question, and why you think it is now on-topic. For a good example of how to ask for reopening, [see this post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5058/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold).

Answer (score 4):

The problem I still see with the question is that there is no clear issue that has been stated.

Why do you think "much of the same" should mean the same as "much the same"?

While this is unclear the question is still unclear.

Comment: Agreed; I don't see any question in the "question".

Comment: @MattGutting I had intended the topic sentence to be my question: 'What are the similarities and differences?'